# PDO is required ERROR

Tags: admin, php, downloader

I've started getting this error when trying to Access Magento downloader, the rest of the site work:

> The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded

Been searching for a fix, but didn't find one...

My php.ini at the bottom has everything that is suggested, it worked before... I don't know what happened..

I had complier enabled, then wanted to install a new extension, so disabled the complier and this happened.

Deleted everything manually form Cache folder and nothing.

I have this in the php.ini, any ideas?

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does PDO show up in `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Yes, PDO Support - Enabled

Comment: Have you re-run compilation, cleared cache etc etc?

Comment: How to correctly re-run compilation? Cache, cleared multiple times inside of magento and manually var/cache

Comment: Just run compilation under `system->tools->compilation`

Comment: Did that, cleared cache (Magento), now the Compilation is enabled and still can't access the Downloader.

Comment: Looks like you are going to have to do a bit of debugging then - not really enough information here to give any more than basic pointers.

Comment: Can it be caused if there is another php ini file on the server? Not in the downloader folder? Not it.. Did a search via CPanel and php.ini only in the route.

Recently installed mem_cached and APC, could it cause this?

Comment: Whatever `phpinfo()` shows - that's what you are running.

Comment: Omg, any suggestions, where I should start?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the Issue, downloader page was missing the PHP.ini.

Copied and pasted the same PHP.ini from the public_html directory to the downloader directory and it started working..

But I don't like this solution, because checked the default Magento instalation and php.ini is not present in the Downloader directory and I don't know, did I hack it or else... If someone has a clue, what could have happend, please post your answer.

Best wishes,

Comment: usually you have a central php.ini in your server config folder. But depending on your hoster, you are maybe not allowed to set these.